# filtering ids from checkboxnames

Tags: php, arrays, array-key, preg-grep

I have some checkboxes that can be checked. They look like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="order[123]" value="1">
```

Now I am checking the formdata and I filter the ids in the order-array this way, before i look them up in the database.

```
$orderids = preg_grep('/^\d+$/', array_keys($_POST['order']));
```

is there a more efficient way for doing this?

Comment: Could `$_POST['order']` ever not be numerical?

Comment: no, in a normal situation it is numeric. these are ids out of a database. but i check the ids for being valid in case that anyone tries to play around with the visible code.

Comment: Hrm good point. You do have options like `$orderids = array_filter(array_keys($_POST['order']), 'is_numeric');` if you so choose to but what you're doing doesn't seem too expensive.

Comment: Yeah it's a little shorter, so I think I will keep my variant. Thanks for your help, Darren!

Answer (score 0):

Using regex, you are ensuring no malicious strings are used, but not checking for viability in the database.  (e.g. `order[999999999999999999999999]` would pass regex, but not be useful in the db.)

The truest validation would be to run them against your database-borne ids using `array_intersect`.

```
   $valid_ids=array_intersect(array_keys($_POST['order']),$db_orderids_array)
```